# alignTop and alignBottom get trampled by android:src

Tags: android, imageview, alignment, scale

Setting `android:src` breaks alignTop/alignBottom, so the `ImageView` grows to the size of the `src`.  Is there a way to enforce alignment again after setting the `src`?

```
<RelativeLayout>

   <ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/foo"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bar"
     android:src="@drawable/pewpew"
     android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/foo" ... />
   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/bar" ... />
```

I would like it to look sorta like this (Qs are the ImageView)

```
QQQ   foo TextView
QQQ   bar TextView
```

Where the image height aligns with the TextViews, and is a square.

Comment: what do you want to use layout like this.

Comment: I updated it with a crude drawing

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the scaleType to "center_inside".

Comment: That gets ignored too.  I think scaleType only works if the width or height is specifically set.  alignTop and alignBottom are not enough for it to go off of I guess

Comment: Unfortunate. Can't say I have any experience to the contrary. When I've run into similar problems in the past, I've mostly relied on somewhat hackish solutions. For instance, can you use a linear layout and negative margins to achieve the same thing? Can you somehow set the image to "match_parent" and size the parent instead? etc.  Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, it may come to that.  maybe ill set the max height to the size of the action bar or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sheep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sheep" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="yyy" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sheep"
        android:text="xxx" />

</RelativeLayout>
```